# How to use Etsy's updateInventory() call to update Stock/Price for a listing

Tags: stock, price, etsy

It is not at all clear to me how to update the price/stock for a listing once it has been created initally using listing->createListing().

To update the stock/price, Etsy's documentation says to call listing->updateInventory().  However, this call requires something called products together with a couple of properties (price_on_property, quantity_on_property and sku_on_property):

- listing_id
- products*
- price_on_property
- quantity_on_property
- sku_on_property

where:

- [products](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/reference/listingproduct%3E) is further defined in their documentation as a combination of [property_values](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/reference/propertyvalue%3E) and [offerings](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/reference/listingoffering) which I have no clue about.
- listing_id is returned from the call to createListing() initially.

Etsy's footnote about price_on_property, stock_on_property and sku_on_property adds to the confusion:

> price_on_property is an array of the property_ids of the properties which price depends on (if any).
>
> quantity_on_property is an array of the property_ids of the properties which quantity depends on (if any).
>
> sku_on_property is an array of the property_ids of the properties
>   which sku depends on (if any).
>
> The update will fail if the supplied values for product sku and offering quantity and price are incompatible with the supplied values of the "on_property_*" fields.
>
> When supplying a price, supply a float equivalent to amount divided by
>   divisor as specified in the Money resource.
>
> The products parameter should be a JSON array of products, even if you only send a single product. All field names in the JSON blob should be lowercase.

Taken from https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/reference/listinginventory#method_updateinventory

Given that the starting point for adding things for sale on Etsy is just to call createListing() with details of the item that I wish to sell (inc stock quantity and price), I do not understand how to call updateInventory() to update the stock and/or price of this item and so can anybody provide some clarity on this matter please (and yes, I have contacted Etsy developer support, but it might take a while for them to respond).

Answer (score 4):

In python - I assume you have the etsy_api module from github.

Etsy product listings have the following structure:

```
ListingProduct = {
   "price_on_property": [
       property_ids
     ], 
   "products": [
          LIST OF PRODUCT VARIATIONS FOR THIS LIST. IF YOU HAVE NO VARIATIONS
          THEN THIS LIST WILL HAVE ONLY 1 PRODUCT.

     ], 
   "quantity_on_property": [], 
   "sku_on_property": []
```

}

To update prices, you need to send back this ListingProduct model, but with the changes you want. Note

- price_on_property is required if you have variations.
- sku_on_property is optional if you have different skus for different
  variations.
- quantity_on_property is optional if you have different quantities on
  variations.

The easiest way I have found is to do the following:

Get the listing_id for the product you want to change price on.
Make a call to the inventory URI to get this listing. I'm doing this to avoid having to construct ListingProduct['products']. It has too much going on with it.

```
 listing_id = 'the product's listing_id'
 ListingProduct = etsy_api.getInventory(listing_id=listing_id)
```

*ListingProduct['products']* is a list of products for this listing. The size of this list is equal to the number of variations that you have.
Take ListingProduct['products'] and for each variation change the price.

If you take a look at ListingProduct['products'], you will see that the changes that need to be done are,

```
ListingProducts['products'][0]['offerings'][0]['price'] = NewPrice
```

If a listing has **2** variations, then change the price on that too

```
ListingProducts['products'][1]['offerings'][0]['price'] = OtherNewPrice
```

Once you do this make a call with the data.

```
data = {
'listing_id': listing_id
'products': json.dumps(ListingProduct['products'])
'price_on_property': 200   #If you have variation
}
```

etsy_api.updateInventory(**data)

Comment: Thank you Duncan for your detailed answer.  Though I'm doing this all from C#, I can't verify answers yet because I'm stuck trying get past their authentication process (again from C#) but together with their Support team's response, I'm sure your response will help.  Many thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

To update the variations for a product in ETSY, you need to use update inventory call from the API (Expecting you are using Etsy module from GitHub).
refer to link https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/getting_started/inventory

The data you need to send with this call will include --

```
array (
     products             => json_encode($products),
     price_on_property    =>
     quantity_on_property =>  
)
```

price_on_property will include the variation property id provided by etsy
quantity_on_property will be included in case of more than one variation attribute

The products index will include an array of variations with the details --

```
[0]  =>  (
          product_id=> 1234,
         property_values" => [
              property_id   => 500,
            property_name => color,
             'values        => [ green ],
         ],
         offerings" => [
             (
                 price => 200
                 quantity => 1,
             )
         )
[1] => and so on...
```

Property Id will be provided by etsy for variation attributes.